# How to get all text from console to string?

Tags: c#, nunit

I do test in that way:

```
NUnit.ConsoleRunner.Runner.Main(new string[]
    {
        System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location,"OpenShop_Firefox.dll",                   
    });
```

And i want to get all text from console to one string. What is the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `Console.Out` to a stream of your choosing:

```
using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
{
    Console.SetOut(stringWriter);

    NUnit.ConsoleRunner.Runner.Main(new string[]
    {
        System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location,
        "OpenShop_Firefox.dll"
    });

    string allConsoleOutput = stringWriter.ToString();
}
```